# Testing for a Palindrome in Python

Tags: python, string, palindrome, splice

I now know there are better solutions for this, but I'm confused as to why I'm getting the result I am.

```
import sys

def isPalindrome(test):
    if len(test) == 1:
        return("Is a palindrome")
    else:
        if test[0] == test[-1]:
            isPalindrome(test[1:-1])
        else:
            return("Not a palindrome")        

print(isPalindrome(sys.argv[1]))
```

On a true palindrome, I get 'None'. When the result is not a palindrome, I get the expected value of 'Not a palindrome'.

Comment: Btw, you can very easily do this with `s == s[::-1]`

Comment: You'll get an `IndexError` when the length of the passed string is an even number. You are checking for condition when len(test) == 1; what if len(test) == 0? For example, with a word abba, in the third recursion you'd end up with an empty string. Your `if` statement can check for both - `if len(test) == 1 or len(test) == 0` or `if len(test) < 2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change to the following line:

```
return isPalindrome(test[1:-1])
```

You have to return a value or the value returned is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion

```
 def isPalindrome (test):
        if test[0] != test[-1]: return ("It is NOT a Palindrome")
        if len(test) == 1: return ("It is a Palindrome")
        else:return test[0] == test[-1] and isPalindrome(test[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue: the 7th line should be:

```
return isPalindrome(test[1:-1])
```

Without return, you call the function, and return None.

Also, as mentioned in other posts, you have an issue with even strings, so add the condition for len(test)==0.

Answer (score 0):

- There is no return path in the if --> True situation. When you return out of the recursion you only return "Is a palindrome" to the level about it, but beyond that you are returning a Null string to the main function.
- You have not accounted for when the recursion becomes an empty string. So the condition  `test[0] == test[-1]` gives a `*** IndexError: string index out of range`

This works:

```
    def isPalindrome(test):
        if (len(test) == 1 or len(test)==0):   
            return("Is a palindrome")

    else:
        print test[0] == test[-1]
        if test[0] == test[-1]:
            return isPalindrome(test[1:-1])
        else:
            print('Not')
            return("Not a palindrome")        

    print(isPalindrome("aa"))
```